# Editing screenshots

Tags: windows, screenshot, image-editing

After taking a screenshot of a big window, I'd like to cut out the middle part(s) and move the sides closer together, so it results in a smaller picture with only relevant details displayed.

Optionally, to indicate that parts are missing, it would be nice to have a way of applying "torn edges" and shadows along the cut.

Which free desktop image editor would be the best for this task? And what are the steps? (I find most image editors have a steep learning curve.)

Comment: Cut out the *middle* parts? I don't think that will make the file smaller..

Comment: He means cut out the middle so that IT is the photo, ignoring what is around that spot.

Comment: @HelpingHand No, he does not. He means to remove the center of the image, and then compact / rearrange the outer edges of the image to reduce image size.

Comment: @Darth Android is right.

Comment: @Seth: not the file size, dimensions of the picture. HelpingHand, I am talking about screenshots specifically, not photos. For example, my browser window is maximized, I want to take a screenshot of it to show toolbars, menus and the statusbar. I am looking for a quickest way to do that. Take a screenshot of the whole window without resizing it, slice out (remove from the picture) the middle horizontally, slice out the middle vertically (I want to display the left and the right ends of the addressbar, but not the middle, which is irrelevant).

Comment: And finally, anybody care to explain why they downvoted my question? This is just for me to learn what I did wrong :(

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @Seth: Windows.

Comment: Also have a shot at Snipping Tool....assuming you are using windows 7 or above..and after that use image editing tools that have already been talked about in answers...will make life lot easier..

Answer (score 4):

Gimp for linux or Windows.  It's the closest thing to free photoshop.

Comment: Mhm. It might take some time to get used to it, but definitely worth it.

Comment: **[paint.NET](http://getpaint.net)** is the closest thing to free Photoshop. It's Windows only, though.

Comment: Paint.net is a lot easier to use than Gimp IMHO, I would recommend using it too.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally suggest using [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).

It is a powerful open-source screenshot tool that can be configured to take a screenshot of a particular area of your desktop, bypassing the extra step of cropping. It lacks some of the photoshop-like effects and tools but it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I was going to recommend this as well but it's missing the effects editing portion.  Great tool though!